Can middleware restrict access to static files stored in the public folder in Next.js?
I'm building a Next.js app where I need to store static files, like videos and images, in the public folder and give them unique names using UUIDs generated with crypto. My goal is to restrict access to these files based on user permissions, so I'm considering using middleware to control access.
I understand that relying on UUIDs alone is considered 'security through obscurity'. My question is specifically about the middleware: can it reliably prevent unauthorized access to files in the public folder?

It seems contradicting, isn't the idea of "public" giving unauthorized access to everyone?

@TP95 Yup. However, If we added middleware to restrict access will anyone still be able to get the files? I didn't find any answer to this anywhere the whole public folder is a mystery in Nextjs
